# How to calculate $\int_C {\sin(z^2)\over(z-3)^2(z+1)(z+4)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Finding $\int_C {\sin(z^2)\over(z-3)^2(z+1)(z+4)}$ which is the counterclockwise circle with center at origin and radius $=5$

I tried finding the Laurent series and then using the Residue Theorem. For the Laurent series I got $${1\over (z-3)^2(z+1)(z+4)}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\over(2n+1)!}z^{4n+2}$$

But when I tried the residue theorem I end up with a negative factorial which isn't possible. I was taught that it is just $$2\pi i*a_{-1}$$ where we just plug in $-1$ for n.

Comment: If I was you, I would use partial fractions  and then evaluate the three integrals individually, using Cauchy's Integral Formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function has $3$ poles and all of them are inside the contour, thus we need to evaluate its residue in these three points, we will use this formula, if $a$ is a pole of order $n$ of $f$ :
$$\operatorname{Res}(f,a) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow a}\frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial z^{n-1}}((z-a)^nf(z))$$

- $z=3$ : The pole has a multiplicity $2$, so :
  $$\operatorname{Res}(f,3) = \frac{1}{1!}\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow 3}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}((z-a)^2f(z))=\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow 3}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left({\sin(z^2)\over(z+1)(z+4)}\right)\\=\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow 3}\frac{2z\cos(z^2)(z+1)(z+4)-\sin(z^2)(2z+5)}{(z+1)^2(z+4)^2}=\frac{168\cos(9)-11\sin(9)}{784}\\=\frac{3\cos(9)}{14}-\frac{11\sin(9)}{784}$$
- $z=-1$ : The pole has a multiplicity $1$, so :
  $$\operatorname{Res}(f,-1)=\frac{\sin(1)}{48}$$
- $z=-4$ : The pole has a multiplicity $1$, so :
  $$\operatorname{Res}(f,-4)=-\frac{\sin(16)}{147}$$

So with Residue theorem :
$$\int_C {\sin(z^2)\over(z-3)^2(z+1)(z+4)}=2\pi i\left(\frac{3\cos(9)}{14}-\frac{11\sin(9)}{784}+\frac{\sin(1)}{48}-\frac{\sin(16)}{147}\right)$$

Comment: does the radius come into play at all?

Comment: Yes you have to evaluate the residues in all the poles because they are all inside the contour. If the radius was $1.5$ for example and the center still the origin, then you would have only evaluated the residue in $-1$ and the  integral would have been equal to $\frac{\pi i\sin(1)}{24}$

Comment: Question, in the $lim z->3$  why isn't is $2zcos(z^2)$

Comment: Oh my bad it's a typo but the final result is still true :)